# Angular2 - FormGroup include and exclude replacements in RC6

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

`include` and `exclude` methods in `FormGroup` class were deprecated in RC5 and then removed in RC6.

So, how are we supposed to build conditional validation? We used to call include/exclude with form control name. Are `addControl` and `removeControl` an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

In rc6 (and future versions) I've solved this issue by using *AbstractControl* *enable* and *disable* methods.

Example:

```
// before (rc5):
//this.formGroup.exclude('controlName');

// after (rc6):
this.formGroup.get('controlName').disable();

// before (rc5):
this.formGroup.include('controlName');

// after (rc6):
this.formGroup.get('controlName').enable();
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's not exactly the same: calling disable() now actually disables (aka grays out) the control, while exclude() did not have this side-effect